# Can I provide a Type as an input to a Type provider in F#?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Are there any pitfall I should be aware of doing so ?

Would you know of existing code dealing with the same pb I might encounter ?

Thks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass types as static parameters to a type provider. The static parameters passed using `MyProvider< "first argument", 42 >` have to be primitive types (like `string`, `int` and similar). I don't see the list anywhere in the documentation, but `Type` is definitely not supported.

The problem with doing this is that you could pass it `typeof<MyType>` where `MyType` is declared in the same file as the file that's using the type provider, and so the F# compiler would have to first compile the first part of a file, then invoke the provider and then continue. This sounds possible, but it is probably low-priority for the F# team.

The best way to pass information about type to a type provider is to give it a type name and then lookup the type using reflection (this will only work if the type is from an already compiled assembly):

```
type MyTest = MyTypeProvider<"System.Int32">
```

Comment: Makes sense. That's why, in my view, we need the notion of execution level. Akin to a computation expression, which can feed the main environment with Types, without ressorting to external DLLs, and whose code is executed before other higher execution levels.